# Floating point loop runs more iterations than should be

Tags: c

I have this loop thats supposed to iterate `lx` times over x (range [-1,1]) and `ly` times over y (range [-1,1]), 9 times total, yet it iterates 16 times! Why is this??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double lx=3,ly=3;
  double du = (1-(-1))/double(lx);
  double dv = (1-(-1))/double(ly);
  int count=0;

  for (double y=-1; y < 1; y += dv)
    for (double x=-1; x < 1; x += du) {

      count++;
    }

  printf("\n\n%d lss\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Because floating point arithmetic isn't exact. You get a value (for instance) of y = 0.99999999999999, so y < 1 is true and your loop executes one too many times.

Comment: it cannot be that imprecise! im not dealing with infinitesimal quantities here. Interestingly enough, if i set lx=ly=4, the loop still runs 4x4=16 times!!

Comment: @Suffem: Yes, it can be that inaccurate. The moment you calculate `2./3.` in binary floating-point, **the result is not 2/3**. It is slightly less, and that is all it takes to make the value of `y` be slightly less than 1 where you might expect 1.

Comment: The OP is just wrong on calculating the deltas, nothing more.

Comment: @Suffern It works with lx=4 because 1/4 has an exact representation in floating point arithmetic, but 1/3 does not.

Answer (score 3):

Seriously?

You are iterating over [-1, -1/3, 1/3, 1].

You can see this by *putting an output statement in the loop to see what's happening.*

Answer (score 0):

I assume your C implementation use IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point for `double`, which is the most common choice.

Every numerical arithmetic system is inexact, so the numbers you work with are not the same numbers you would get with exact mathematics.

The statement `double du = (1-(-1))/double(lx);` sets `du` to the `double` value that is closest to 2/3, which is 0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625.

In the first iteration of the outer loop, `y` is -1. When `du` is added to it at the end of each iteration, the results are:

- -0.33333333333333337034076748750521801412105560302734375,
- 0.3333333333333332593184650249895639717578887939453125, and
- 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.

Obviously, that last value of `y` is less than 1, so the loop continues for another iteration.

Loop iterators should usually use integer values, so that it is easy to ensure exact arithmetic is used. You can scale the iterator to produce other desired values:

```
for (int iy = 0; iy < 4; ++iy)
{
    double y = iy * 2 / 3. - 1;
    …
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the difference between your start and end point in a different way here as you're using doubles here.

So instead of `end - start` use `end - start + 1.0` and you're done.

Comment: Because when you specify an integer range like [-1, 1[ you only have 2 number in between, but with doubles you have a lot more, because 0.9999999 would also fit in there. So you have to make the interval one unit larger to get to the real width.